# Why doesn't my script accept a valid date as user input?

Tags: python

The script works fine if I give it a date of `01/12/2021`. But if I give it another date like today's as `01/18/2021` or any other the script says that the date isn't valid and prompts the user to enter the date in again.

```
def print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number):
    inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': ")
    day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')
    isValidDate = True
    try:
        datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
    except ValueError :
        isValidDate = False
        print("Date is not valid.")
        print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)

    if(isValidDate) :
        print(f"Input date is valid: {inputDate}")
        format= "%m%d%Y"
        inputDate = datetime.strptime(inputDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
        inputDate = inputDate.strftime(format)
    else:
        print(f"Input date is not valid: {inputDate}")
        print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)
    myclient = connect_db()
    mydb = myclient["aws_inventories"]
    instance_col = "ec2_list_" + inputDate
    instance_col = mydb[instance_col]
    print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)
```

This is the output I get if I put in some different dates:

```
Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': 01/12/2021
Input date is valid: 01/12/2021
Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': 01/13/2021
Date is not valid.
Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': 01/14/2021
Date is not valid.
Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': 01/15/2021
Date is not valid.
Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': 01/16/2021
Date is not valid.
```

Why won't my script accept any date other than `01/12/2021` as valid input?

Comment: There are only 12 months in a year, although it appears as though that's not exactly your issue, you might want to update your output to not show dd/mm/yyy

Comment: Don’t call your function within itself to start over. Use a while loop. What you are doing is called recursion, and isn’t appropriate here.

Comment: there are only 12 months in a year, prehaps you are confusing the dd/mm/yyyy format with mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: I am voting to close this as caused by a typo / not reproducible. `day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')` should be `month,day,year = inputDate.split('/')` for an input of `'01/13/2021'`. If you print the error, from the exception, it is `Date is not valid. month must be in 1..12`. FYI: Questions caused by typos will get closed, and deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. Yet, you are inputting (in what I assume) is a `mm/dd/yyyy` format. If you try to parse `01/18/2021` in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, then you would get the result that it is the first day in the 18th month in the year 2021 (which, of course, is impossible - there are only 12 months in the year). To fix this, you are going to either have to change your format to `mm/dd/yyyy` or input as `18/01/2021`.

To change the input checker to `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
def print_reports(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number):
    inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'mm/dd/yyyy': ")
    month, day, year = inputDate.split('/') # changed order of month and day
    isValidDate = True
    try:
        datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    except ValueError:
        isValidDate = False
        print("Date is not valid.")
        print_reports(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number)

    if isValidDate:
        print(f"Input date is valid: {inputDate}")
        format = "%m%d%Y"
        inputDate = datetime.strptime(inputDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
        inputDate = inputDate.strftime(format)
    else:
        print(f"Input date is not valid: {inputDate}")
        print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)
    myclient = connect_db()
    mydb = myclient["aws_inventories"]
    instance_col = "ec2_list_" + inputDate
    instance_col = mydb[instance_col]
    print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)
```

Note that it looks like you are using the function `datetime` with the `dd/mm/yyyy` format, but you are using the `mm/dd/yyyy` format with `datetime.strptime` in the original code. In this code, it only uses the `mm/dd/yyyy` format, but you can always edit this easily to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

**Edit:** Looks like you are using recursion. Of course, instead, you should be using a `while` loop, as recursion is not needed here. Also, you are using the `isValidDate` variable, but that is never actually used or needed:

```
def print_reports(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number):
    while True:
        inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'mm/dd/yyyy': ")
        month, day, year = inputDate.split('/') # changed order of month and day
        try:
            datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        except ValueError:
            print("Date is not valid.")
            continue

        print(f"Input date is valid: {inputDate}")
        format = "%m%d%Y"
        inputDate = datetime.strptime(inputDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
        inputDate = inputDate.strftime(format)

        myclient = connect_db()
        mydb = myclient["aws_inventories"]
        instance_col = "ec2_list_" + inputDate
        instance_col = mydb[instance_col]
```

Answer (score 1):

`01/16/2021` is not a valid date, since the year has only 12 months and not 16 ;).
Your code should be like this:

```py
def print_reports(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number):
    inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': ")
    day, month, year = inputDate.split('/')
    try:
        datetime(int(day), int(month), int(year))
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Date is not valid.")
        return False

    print(f"Input date is valid: {inputDate}")
    inputDate = datetime.strptime(inputDate,"%d/%m/%Y")
    return True
myclient = connect_db()
mydb = myclient["aws_inventories"]
instance_col = mydb["ec2_list_" + inputDate]
while not success:
    global success
    success = print_reports(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number)
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, looks like he's printing one way and formatting another

Comment: Recursively calling print reports is not correct